# Javascript: Create new rows from Array

Tags: javascript, adobe

Apologies for a possible basic question. New at JS and I'm likely using the wrong terms in my search.

I have this variable;

```
myArray = ['000001', '0000002', '0000003', '0000004']
```

What I ideally want to do is create a new row for each value held in this array - regardless of how many values are present (so 1 value = 1 row, 50 values = 50 rows)

So for the above I would want the following result;

```
Row    newVar
1      0000001
2      0000002
3      0000003
4      0000004
```

I am building this in Adobe Campaign - appreciate any useful answers!

Comment: Are you sure `myArray` is an array?

Comment: Should be myArray = [000001,0000002,0000003,0000004]

Comment: `0000001` is a just a literal for a number 1. You'll have to use strings, i.e. `['0000001', '0000002']` etc. Or, even better, just use a padding function.

Comment: @raina77ow is right. `000001` would be converted to `1` if it's not a string.

Comment: Also you have to define in what format you want the results?? Array literal, Object literal?

Comment: Do you want to create a `HTML` table out of the `myArray`?

Comment: I (badly it seems) used those values as an example. The real values are currently 4242971,4241831,4241893. These are a primary key of a table and will only ever increment.

I then want to add these into another variable to pass this through to a query which will match all values against the table these keys belong to.

Comment: So you want to pass the array values to a query? Where do you even need the table with row indexing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map` for this:

```js
data = ['000001', '0000002', '0000003', '0000004'];

var rows = data.map(function (item, index) { return [index, item]; });

console.log(rows);

var rowsAsObject = data.map(function (item, row) { return { row: row, item: item }; });

console.log(rowsAsObject);
```

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere this is for Adobe Campaign and it uses a weird native JS. It returns this error;

    JST-310000 Error while compiling script 'WKF129/js5' line 4: invalid assignment left-hand side (line='var rows = data.map((item, index) => [index, item]); ' token='=> [index, item]); ').

Comment: Ah, this JS engine might not support ES6 function literals yet. I'll adopt my example.

Comment: It really doesn't like the map function either...


JST-310000 Error while compiling script 'WKF129/js5' line 11: data.map is not a function.

Comment: Okay, let's paddle back a bit: do you have an ECMAScript Version or some spec handy that explains what is available in your context?

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.map and create dynamic Table

**Javascript**

```
var myArray = ['0000001','0000002','0000003','0000004'];

var ar = myArray.map(function(value, i){
        return '<tr><td class="row">'+i+'</td><td class="value">'+value+'</td></tr>'
})

document.getElementById('tb').innerHTML = ar.join('');
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Row</th>
    <th>Value</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="tb">

 </tbody>
</table>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w5as3q49/1/)

Comment: The JavaScript native to Adobe Campaign is slightly odd (I can't seem to find exactly what it uses). It returns this error;

    JST-310000 Error while compiling script 'WKF129/js5' line 6: myArray.map is not a function.

Comment: @moody_mage i am not sure how Adobe campaign works. You can use the polyfill of Array map copy it from here -
 > "https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map"

If not try to use for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Some observations :

- `myArray` should be an array.i.e. `var myArray = [000001,0000002,0000003,0000004]`
- As `0000001` is nothing but `number 1`. first convert it into string if you want it in 0000001 format.

**DEMO**

```js
var myArray = ["0000001","0000002","0000003","0000004"];    
    
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  var row = table.insertRow();
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = i+1;
  cell2.innerHTML = myArray[i];
}
```

```css
table,td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<td>Row</td>
<td>newVar</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Adobe Campaigns native JS is an obscure one. Your script returns this error;

JST-310000 Error while compiling script 'WKF129/js5' line 22: document.getElementById is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate output in required format.

```
myArray = ["0000001","0000002","0000003","0000004"];    

logInfo("Row\tnewVar");
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    logInfo(i+"\t"+myArray[i]);
}
```